# Can adding a column affect the constraints of 2 tables in a database SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, constraints, table-relationships

I have a table `[Users]` and the columns are `ID, Fname, Mname`. I also have `[UsersBranches]` with columns `ID, userid, branchid`.

These two tables have a relation to each other via `Users.ID = UsersBranches.Userid`

I want to add a new column `Lname` to `[Users]`. Are my constraints going to be corrupted if a add a new column or not?

Because I am currently updating our company's database and they want to add `Lastname` which is `Lname` if add to database.

Any help is very very much appreciated..

Comment: why use a shortening 'Lname' when 'Lastname' is 3 chars longer and reads so much better? Use descriptive naming!

Comment: ***WHAT*** constraints are you talking about? Except for the FK-PK relationship, you haven't mentioned any constraints..... but in general, just adding a column will **not** "corrupt" any existing constraints

Comment: thanks for all the commenst I appreciate it much @MitchWheat ok i'll take note aout descriptive naming thanks for suggestion "D

Answer (score 1):

Adding a new column outside relation fields has no side effect and can be done at any moment. The only thing you have to bear in mind is that your Lname should allow null values if you currently have records inside these tables.

Comment: yes I thanks for the answer. I will take not that :D

Comment: by the way I come up with adding a new column... then is it ok to  drop that column if I want to?

Comment: so long as you're not touching your foreign key fields, change the schema the way you want. add, remove, alter .. etc. just take note if you drop cols then you'll lose data along with it.